# How to enable facelets in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA and I am having a hard time figuring out how to create a simple JSF project. I used eclipse so I really am not familiar on how to properly create modules in IntelliJ. I tried creating a new project > Java Module > clicked JSF and I successfully created a JSF module but it's using JSP pages instead of facelets XHTML. How can I use facelets and is there a way to create XHTML pages using context menus? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*New* > *JavaEE Web Page*. *Kind* should be *Facelets page*.

Comment: Thank you. Please tell us *why* should it be Facelets page - and not JSF, which is the other option. What is the difference here?